# How to edit PHP.ini file. I have tried a lot but failed to find in Linux based Web Server on my Domain

Tags: php, linux

I don't know where is php.ini file in Linux based web server on my domain. There are several things to edit in php.ini file.
How i can. I don't want to contact to Web Server Admin to do that.. I want to do it by Myself. I have uploaded a php.ini file into home directory but still it is not working.. how i can do that..

Please Help

Comment: Did You restart web server after?

Comment: What type of hosting package do you have and who is your hosting provider? Normally, you will need SSH access to your server in order to edit php.ini files.

Comment: how to restart web server..? Can you please tell me??

Comment: I just logged in through cpanel and In File Manager, i have uploaded php.ini file and thats all. I dont know how to restart server which is online ...

Comment: Why do you want to edit php.ini file? You can update any variable from php coding.

Comment: currently i cannot see phpinfo also.. I made a php file in which i wrote " <?php phpinfo() ?> " And it is showing this Warning Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/doshremi/public_html/phpinfo.php on line 2

Comment: How i can update via PHP.. I want to enable short_open_tag How i can do it via php..

Comment: @walkingRed How i can restart web server??

Comment: Using command line `service apache restart` (with sudo)

Comment: @walkingRed service apache restart with sudo? How to do that. Can you please tell me the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Run The following

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

You will get the full path of php.ini

Answer (score 1):

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" | sed 's#.* ##'
```

will output the file path to the terminal edit it with your favorite tool i.e. vim, vscode

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" | sed 's#.* ##' | xargs vim
```

opens you php ini in [vim](https://www.vim.org/) a linux console text editor

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File" | sed 's#.* ##' | xargs cat
```

prints you php ini to console

---

It is also possible to create a simple file with

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

and let it be interpreted by a php enviroment. There the file will be listed (amongst a lot of other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

For a Debian Linux : /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: I dont know it is a Debian Linux or something else. But it is Linux Based Cpanel what i can see there..and There is etc folder also. but it is empty

Comment: currently i cannot see phpinfo also.. I made a php file in which i wrote " <?php phpinfo() ?> " And it is showing this Warning Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/doshremi/public_html/phpinfo.php on line 2

Comment: Hm... I think you can modify php.ini from Cpanel, but if you can't, you will have to connect to your server by SSH and find/modify the good php.ini file

Comment: for above warning Remove the phpinfo string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file

Answer (score 0):

make a php file with the following line

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

and open it from browser . you can find complete configuration details .

Comment: which following line?

Comment: Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/doshremi/public_html/phpinfo.php on line 2

Comment: what linux distibution you are using in ubuntu it is located in /etc/php5/apache2

Comment: how i can identify that what it is.. But etc folder is Empty here.

Comment: if you are using shared hosting you cannot access the configuration . It is only possible under vps or dedicated server.

Comment: here is attached Snapshot of Cpanel.Please check you will definitely understand its hosting account   https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/4TIzKYjK1IX/z2z7onou~aAxWEWs

Comment: it is  just shared hosting you cannot edit php.ini  . b'coz you only have limited access.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in SSH to find all files named "php.ini"

```
# find / -type f -name php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

first login using ssh like this.

ssh username@ip_addrerss

for example

ssh root@255.255.255.255
and press enter it will ask you for password, enter your password.

you will find php.ini here.

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

use vi editor to edit it.

then you have to restart apache.use this

sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

For Cpanel : php.ini file is located in the /usr/local/lib/ directory

Warning Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons

In order to eliminate this error message you need to do ONE of the following things:

- Remove the phpinfo string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file
- Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don't have an access to the php.ini* file
- Change hosting provider which allows the running of the phpinfo function.

For Custom PHPINI File for your Linux cPanel Site:

http://www.arcserver.it/knowledgebase/36/How-to-Create-a-Custom-PHPINI-File-for-your-LinuxorcPanel-Site.html